# How does nested SELECT and NOT IN work in knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to write this query in knex and am stuck.
I currently have 3 tables (group_tasks, completed_group_tasks and group_users)

I want to filter out the results when grouptask_id from completed_group_tasks is the same as the innerjoin.

```
SELECT * FROM group_tasks INNER JOIN group_users ON group_users.group_id = group_tasks.group_id WHERE user_id = 2 AND grouptask_id NOT IN (SELECT grouptask_id FROM completed_group_tasks WHERE user_id = 2)
```

I tried writing this:

```
db.from('group_users')
        .select('groups.group_id', 'group_name')
        .innerJoin('groups', 'group_users.group_id', 'groups.group_id')
        .where({user_id: user_id})
        .whereNotIn('grouptask_id', function() {
            this.from('completed_group_tasks')
                .select('grouptask_id')
                .where({user_id: user_id})
        })
```

This fails stating `column "grouptask_id" does not exist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subquery in Knex needs to be a separate Knex builder.

```
db.from('group_users')
  .select('groups.group_id', 'group_name')
  .innerJoin('groups', 'group_users.group_id', 'groups.group_id')
  .where({ user_id: user_id })
  .whereNotIn(
    'grouptask_id',
    db
      .from('completed_group_tasks')
      .select('grouptask_id')
      .where({ user_id: user_id }),
  );
```